# Sum elements of matrix with multithreading/multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, matrix, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing and multithreading in Python and I'm trying to solve this problem:

Given a n x m matrix, I have to sum all elements of the matrix with multiprocessing or threading (I'd like to see both solutions). ***Each thread has to sum to a variable*** `sumThreads` (I'm not aware if with multiprocess this can be achieved). I have to use n processes/threads.

This is what I've tried so far with threads

```py
import threading

matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]

def run(n):
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        sumThreads += matrix[n][i] 

sumThreads = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(i,))
    t.start() 

print(sumThreads)
```

However I get the following error

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sumThreads' referenced before assignment`

If I place `run` below the starting the threads, it tells me run isn't defined.

What I expect is something like:

```py
sumThreads = 0

matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]] #Prints 21
```

Here `n = 3` and output should be `21` with thread/process `1` adding `1+2`,  thread/process `2` adding `3+4` and thread/process `3` adding `5+6`

Comment: Pass in `sumThreads` as a kwarg to the thread.

Comment: You could use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) to collect the results which has an equivalent for multiprocessing as well.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Thanks, I've tried it passing sumThreads as a kwarg worked. But, I don't know why it works. Why can't I pass `SumThreads` as an `int` ?

Comment: For the other threads to access it, you have to share it to those threads via the kwarg (key word argument). Prior to that it was local to the originating thread and therefore not available to other threads. I'll add it to an answer below.

Comment: Please vote and hit the check mark next to it to close this question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in your shared object `sumThreads` as a key-word argument or kwarg for the [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

```
t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(i,), kwargs={'sumThreads':sumThreads})
```

For the other threads to access it, you have to share it to those threads via the kwarg. Prior to that it was local to the originating thread and therefore not available to other threads. I'll add it to an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The full code would be

```py
import threading

matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]

def run(n, **totalSum):
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        sumThreads['sumThreads'] += matrix[n][i]

sumThreads = {"sumThreads":0}
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(i,), kwargs=sumThreads)
    t.start() 
print(sumThreads['sumThreads']) #prints 21
```